# Should I use Google Webmaster Tools’ "change of address" if merging two sites?

Tags: redirect, seo, google-search-console

Two sites, with very similar content. Both existing and well established. I've set up 301 redirects to site A from site B.

Should I use the Webmaster 'change of address' feature to support the merge?

From what I've read, it seems more suited to an old domain transferring to a new domain. Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

The use the change of address tool in Google Webmaster will help you to manage the transition needed by Google to index your new URLs at the new address, while minimizing impact to your current ranking in the SERP.

You can use it together with a "Standard" 301 Moved Permanently redirect, which will pass Page Rank from site A to site B.